# Knockout JS data binding with JqueryMobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I am using knockout js for front end data binding with JqueryMobile, I have a view which is bind with Knockout js Object call DataGrid. DataGrid object contains object array which populated in a table(use fooTable).When user click a row, it should load in another page.I want to bind selected object to the UI but currently It is not happening.It only binds DataGrid object to the UI,Could anyone guide me through this?

```
//Data Grid Object
function DataGrid(){
    var self = this;
    self.dataGrid = ko.observableArray();

    self.addTicketToGrid = function(ticket){
        self.dataGrid.push(ticket);
    }
}

function Ticket(jsTicket){
   var self = this;
   ko.mapping.fromJS(jsTicket, {}, this);
   this.formattedDate = moment(self.date(),"YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss").format("MM-DD HH:MM");
   this.getRunTicket = function(){
     servicet.getTicket(self);
  }
```

}

```
getTicketListFromDB : function (){
     var rtGrid =  new DataGrid();
     var rtList = PortalDB.getObjList(); // Get objects from local storage
        for(var i = 0; i <rtList.length; i++){
            var rt = rtList[i];
            var ticket1 = new Ticket(rt); //Create new Ticket object
            rtGrid.addTicketToGrid(ticket1); // Add Ticket to Grid 
        }
        ko.applyBindings(rtGrid);
}
```

Html for grid

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach : dataGrid">
      <tr>
        <td><span data-bind="text : number(),click: getTicket"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text : formattedDate></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text : operatorName()"></span></td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
```

Here when user click the first column getTicket function calls and load to Ticket detail UI, I want to bind selected Ticket object with the loaded UI, but it's not working for me, getTicket function implementation

```
goToRunTicketDetails: function(ticket){
    $.mobile.navigate( "#ticketDetailsPage" );
    alert(ticket.ticketNumber) // this alert shows the ticketNumber   
    ko.applyBindings(ticket);
}
```

html for ticketDetailsPage

```
    <div data-role="page" id="runTicketDetailsPage" data-theme="b">
       <div data-role="content" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Ticket No (<span data-bind="text: ticketNumber"></span>)</h1>
        <button id="save" data-icon="save"  class="ui-btn-right" data-bind="click: refreshGrid">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

In here `ticketNumber` not displaying any value, but If I put `dataGrid().length` instead of ticketNumber, it displays the size of the datagrid,Can anyone tell me what is the wrong with this code?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You might find this blog post to be quite useful http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2012/10/23/integrating-knockout-and-jquerymobile.html

Comment: Thank you for this I found out the solution.